# How to bind tooltip to a button for different conditions

Tags: wpf, data-binding, prism, delegatecommand

How to bind tooltip dynamically for different conditions
we have 2 Projects in the solution v are using PRISM framework
GeneralBL contains the business logic and 
StudentManagementUI contains the Usercontrols ,views and ViewModels

Have StudentStatusUserControl.xaml.cs contains a Telerik RadButton

```
                 <telerik:RadButton Name="button1" Content="Stauses" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" FontSize="12" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                prism:Click.Command="{Binding ButtonstatusCommand}">
```

this is enabled for a specific condition & when it is disabled we have to show the mouse hover or tooltip info depending on the condition

In the StudentStatusViewModel.cs

```
    private bool CanExecuteButtonStatusCommand(object o)
    {
        return SharedLogicBL.CanExecuteButtonStatusCommand(controller,dataService,  _selectedItem);
    }
```

SharedLogicBL.cs in GeneralBL project

```
      public static bool CanExecuteUnplannedInspection(BaseController controller, DataService dataService, SDataItem selectedItem)
    {
       if(controller.currentuser.Isallowed())
          {
            if(selectedItem!=null)
               {
                 Orders = dataservice.GetOrders(selectedItem);
                  return !Orders.Any();
                }
            }
            else
               return false;
       }
```

In the above method check to see if the user has the rights, if not Tooltip on the button "User doesn't have the rights"
Let first condition is true , in the Orders.Any() returns false then we should display "the selected student has no orders"

Also have a dependency property in the StudentStatusUserControl.xaml.cs for this StudentStatusUserControlBL in the GeneralBL project

Comment: add an INPC property in your ViewModel `string Tip` and bind the button ToolTip to the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public property in your viewmodel that you can databind the telerik button tooltip text to.

```
public string Button1TooltipText
{
    get { 
         if (!controller.currentuser.Isallowed())
           { return "User doesn't have the rights" }
         else
           { 
             if (!SharedLogicBL.CanExecuteButtonStatusCommand(controller, dataService, _selectedItem))
                 return "the selected student has no orders";
             else
                 return "Execute the unplanned inspection";
           }

         }
}
```

Since this property depends on the currently selected item, you'll need to call NotifyPropertyChanged("Button1TooltipText") when _selectedItem changes.